# How to do research after Ph.D when you have less time?

Tags: research-process

I have joined an institute as an assistant professor from some time. I have done my PhD in computational mathematics. I am very much interested in research and spend lot of time and I really enjoy it. During my Ph.D I have done my research independently as well as some time with Ph.D supervisor. During my Ph.D  I use to spend large amount of my time in research. The problem is now I have been involved in academic and other activities, so I am not able to spend that amount of time. I am not able to collaborate with others as there is no collaborator in the university.

**Question** : How to do research after Ph.D when you have less time?

Comment: it may help to tell us at country you are in. Where I'm located the way to gain more research time is to apply for and be granted large external research grants which pay a portion of your salary and buy you out of teaching and admin. I have one starting nect month that ensures 75% of my time is research.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ideas. The first is to set aside some time each week for your own research. A few hours in a block, perhaps.

The next is to keep a research notebook (or a small pack of index cards) with you at all times so that you can (a) review existing cards and (b) jot down any ideas that occur. Especially keep ideas for things that might be explored when you have he time.

Third, and very important, is to develop a circle of collaborators wherever you can find them. If not possible at your own university, perhaps at a nearby one. But there are also conferences that you can probably attend and meet people with similar interests. Follow up with authors of papers you find interesting. Modern communication makes even international collaboration quite easy if you all write a common language.

Doctoral study is very intense and most people have few obligations other than the research. That changes for many upon graduation, especially if teaching is a big part of the job. But you can also interest a few advanced undergraduates in your research, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks professor ⚘

Answer (score 3):

One of the biggest shocks of becoming faculty is that actually doing research is no longer the biggest part of your job.

Certainly for me, the main source of collaboration for research as a faculty member is the graduate students I mentor. With a few hours a week, advising others on their work is a really efficient use of time, and then, when time allows or it is really necessary, I get the pleasure of helping them directly with a particularly difficult problem.

Other than that, I collaborate with people a many different universities, both in different cities in the same country and in other countries. Skype, Slack, various file sharing platforms all make long-distance collaboration perfectly possible in the modern age.